# Inner join with where clause PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have the following query

```
$query = "SELECT userRoles.UserRoleType
FROM user
INNER JOIN userRoles
ON user.RoleID = userRoles.RoleID
WHERE( user.UserName = '" . $username . "' AND user.Password = '" . $pass . "')";
```

Where $username and $pass are variables passed through the form

The query runs fine in phpMyadmin but for some reason it wont run in PHP even though it appears to be returning information.

Tried changing the query multiple times such as moving the WHERE clause above the join, checking table names, googling etc.

Comment: What is actually in `$username` and `$password`? Did you `echo $query`?

Comment: both variables hold strings. Im new to PHP is there a way to echo the variable from another page? i.e. a php page that contains HTML?

Comment: How does it _appear to be returning information_? And did you escape those `$username` & `$pass` parameters, and if so, with what? Also, are you sure this user _has_ a roletype?

Comment: @Wrikken Yes i have only one user stored currently. I removed the join and the query ran just fine. I also tested the other tables integrity by selecting all records from that table which also ran fine.

Comment: `echo` outputs its arguments immediately, so you can just write it right after your `$query = ...` and look for it somewhere in page.

Comment: after that, do an `echo $query; die;` and give us the ouput.

Comment: If you _removed the join and the query ran just fine_, I stress again the fact that there may not be an entry in the `userRoles` table for that `user.RoleID`.

Comment: I received no output when echoing the variable, so in fact it is not actually returning anything, would this indicate an error in the sql string?

Comment: @Wrikken the query returned the role type along with the user in phpmyadmin so i am assuming that the query is fine. HOWEVER... when i ran the query i simply removed the variables and replaced them with my own hardcoded string for the WHERE clause

Comment: Ah, if you also hardcoded the variables when removing the join, then yes, we're back on escaping `$username` & `$password` for database use.

Comment: @KyleT: you are giving us to little data to work with I fear, which has resulted in a lot of guessing by me & others. Can you whip up a script which exhibits the errors in a few lines (< 20 lines or so), and share that entire script instead of just that query? That would make it a lot easier for us to answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46376/discussion-between-kylet-and-wrikken)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm turning in for the night, looking forward to your code snippet exhibiting the problem ;)

Comment: @Wrikken Thank you i will post the solution in case others have a similar problem, good night

Answer (score 0):

Question resolved

When returning the query as an array i had an if statement like this:

```
if($result[0]>0)
{
  //do something with returned data
}
```

To resolve the problem i simply had to check if the size of the array was greater than zero indicating that a record had been found.

**Here is the solution**

```
if($result>0)
{
  //do something with returned data
}
```